# python pygobject and functions that return an array

Tags: python, pygobject

I'm trying to port some python code that uses gtop. I've replaced the old usage of gtop

```
import gtop
[...]
gtop.proclist()
```

by

```
from gi.repository import GTop
[...]
proclist = GTop.glibtop_proclist()
GTop.glibtop_get_proclist(proclist, 0, 0)
```

The C function get_proclist return a **pid_t***, but in python it returns an **int**.
I don't know if it is a limitation of introspection, or I need to cast or do something on the returned value...

I found a workaround using psutils, but I'd like to stick to the already used dependencies (GLib, GTK, etc)

Comment: Is `pid_t` not an `int` on Windows, or do you not want the PID at all?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in LibGTop2, I submitted a patch adding missing Python bindings to make it work: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=734170